# How to create and maintain session?

Tags: cgi, session

I am using HTML, C, CGI. Now I need to create and maintain sessions.How can I do that?

If any tutorial talks about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, if you create a session using a CGI program written in Perl, can you access it from a CGI program written in C?  If so, it depends on how the Perl script stores its session data.

If you use [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/Tutorial.pm), it looks like that's capable of storing session data in plain files, Berkeley DB files, or MySQL databases.  All of those can be accessed by C programs, but you'll have to write C code to get the value of the `CGISESSID` cookie or query parameter, and look it up in the session file or database.  Essentially, you have to reimplement at least the core functionality of CGI::Session in C.

If you're using something other than CGI::Session, it still has to store its session data somewhere, so you should still be able to access it from your C programs.  You'll need to determine where and how it's stored, though.